# Why does pycharm miss this coverage hit when running pytest?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, coverage.py

I have some test cases that are running against python code that accesses a database using the latest version of PyCharm.  All of my test cases are passing and (other than the #pragma no cover lines) am expecting 100% coverage.  In some cases the code is not marked as hit when in fact I know it is because I set breakpoints in the test run and single step through the code.

The image below shows one example, 104,106 and 107 are marked as not hit but they most definitely are hit.  I snipped the screen shot showing the line at a break-point on a line that apparently wasn't marked as a hit.

Here is the function, that lives in the module biz (there is no class/object involved, a straight function call), that has incomplete coverage even though when run for testing I can single step through every line:

```py
    def get_schedule_d():
        try:
            with connection() as conn:
                with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    query = f"""LONG QUERY"""
                    cursor.execute(query)
                    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
                    for row in cursor:
                        yield dict(zip(columns, row))
         except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:  # pragma: no cover
             return
```

Here is the test case that calls it.  biz.py has a handful of functions that access a database.  It is not a class or object, just functions in a module named biz.

```py
    def test_get_schedule():
        sc = list(biz.get_schedule('2019-12-9'))
        scd = list(biz.get_schedule_d('2019-12-9'))
        assert len(sc) == 95
        assert len(scd) == 95
```

Here is the indication of incomplete coverage...with a break point being hit at a line marked with no coverage:

[image]

Comment: it would help if test setup and definition were shown as well as the original function

Comment: is cursor mocked?

Comment: Nope, hitting live database.

Comment: the function you showed does not help at all. what is `biz`? what is its definition? we can not help if we are given piece meal information